How to truncate final result in java (Recursion)
I am working on this code that has this design
public static String combine(String first, String second, int n);

so this takes 2 strings and returns the 2 Strings for n times. Ex. the input
("Good", "Morning", 3) the output should be "Good Morning Good".
My implementation is using recursion where the base case is stating if n is less than or equal to 0 that it should return "". For any number greater than 0, it should concatenate the first + " " + second + " " + combine(first, second, n-1). Then this results in the output, "Good Morning Good Morning Good Morning", so now I am thinking of taking the length of the result and only taking the substring from 0 to half the length of the result string. However, when I try this, I get "Good Mornin" instead. I'm sort of stumped on how I can truncate it to "Good Morning Good".
Here is my code:
public static String combine(String first, String second, int n) {

        if(n <= 0) {
            return "";
        }
        else {
            String result = first + " " + second + " " + combine(first, second, n - 1);
            int d = result.length();
            
             
            return result.substring(0, d/2);    
            }   
    }

Thank you

Think closely about what n means. Is this the number of pairs first + " " + second? Or is it something else? Your answer might change either the base case or the recursive case or both.

The substring() call is definitely wrong. As your example shows, it is likely to truncate in the middle of a word. Don't try to truncate the result. Instead, you should fix the algorithm directly in order to combine the words correctly to begin with.

You wrote (in your question): takes 2 strings and returns the 2 Strings for n times This is what your code does, i.e. it prints the two strings three times. However you also wrote: the output should be "Good Morning Good" which is not printing the two strings three times. In other words, I see a mismatch between the requirement and the expected output. This implies to me that either you didn't understand the requirement or that your expected output is wrong. I think you need to re-check the requirement including the required output.

maybe first + " " + second + " " + combine(first, second, n - 2) (- 2 instead of - 1 since two strings are being concatenated) and adding a second base case for n == 1

I’m assuming you want to return a String that consists of first and second alternating. If you insist on recursion, then the following should work:
public static String combine(String a, String b, int n){
    if(n == 2){
        return a + " " + b;
    }
    return combine(a, b, n-1) + " " + (n % 2 == 1 ? a : b);
}


simpler ... return a + " " + combine(b, a, n-1); (I would also change the base case:  if (n <= 0) return ""; else return a + " " + combine(b, a, n-1);)

@user85421 You should post this as an answer. This is by far the simplest and most direct solution: only concatenate one word, then swap the order in the recursive call.

This answer will fail for combine("foo", "bar", 1) which I assume is valid input.

@Code-Apprentice I figured OP could handle the special cases by themself. My answer would also fail if n = -42.

public static String combine(String first, String second, int n) {
    if(n<=0){
        return "";
    }
   
    String str = n >= 2 ? first + " " + second : n == 1 ? first : "";
    return str + " " + combine(first, second, n-2);
}
    </code>


why \b? And when do you expect n == 1 in the statement before the last return? Actually we can only expect n >= 2 there, unless n < 0 (and so it is not very clear that this is being tested)

/b is for anothe case which is not applicable here

when n==1 then it add only first string and
when n==2 it add first and second string and return it.
For any other  number which is greater the 2 then it add both first and second string and call combine() to get remaining iteration.
it is for when n=3 then it add first + second + combine(first , second , n-2).
when call combine() n==1 then it return first string only and recursion terminate.
so resultant string is first + second + first.

but 1) why are you testing for n == 1 after if (n == 1) { return first; } -- it cannot be 1 after the return! 2) you missed the base case if n == 0! 2) why testing >= 2 it can only be greater than 2  after the previous if statements, assuming point 2 corrected, if (n <= 0) return ... else if (i==1) return ... else if (n == 2) return

obey I understand n==2 case and I missed n==0 case.
